# Do you use a definite article or zero article followed by a prepositional phrase

Tags: articles, definite-article, prepositional-phrases, zero-article

In the following two (similar) sentences the definite article is used in one, but not the other.

1 Capital letters are used for **the** names of people,places and languages.

2.Capital letters are used for names of people,places and languages.

Both sound natural to me. I would be grateful if someone could tell me if one is more technically correct than the other and if so, why? i.e would you use **the** for a specific meaning Vs **no article.**

Answer (score 1):

General things don't require the:
An apple a day is good for you.
Apples are good for you.

**Capital letters are used for names of people, places and languages.**

Comment: But this answer misses that fact that _the_ is also possible here, even for the general case. Without an _of_, you can't use _the_ unless you are speaking about a specific set of names. But _the names of people_ is fine in the general case.

Comment: @ColinFine Yes, possible but not necessary at all. "Names of people in the directory are alphabetized" Yes? Why use: The names of the people there? Compare: "The names of the people in that street are all Polish" (specific) . General things do not require the.

Comment: No, they do not require it, but they allow it, and that needs explaining.

Comment: @ColinFine My opinion is that by using "the names of people" you are no longer in a general case. "The names of people on the list are not right". i.e., some specific list drawn up by somebody.

Comment: so you believe that the OP's no 1 is appropriate only if the "people, places and languages" are a specific list? I don't agree.

Comment: Yes, that's right. As in: Capital letters are used for **the** names of people, places and languages [we write about in our publications.]

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the sentence makes it easier to determine it is a definite or zero article

Capital letters are used for the names (X) - *any name, not specific names that are known or previously mentioned*

Capital letters are used for names (O) - *any letter for any name*